# creating a new handle to class through a function in c++

Tags: c++

I am not sure if my title makes any sense. I am trying to implement a queue class in c++. Below is my q.cpp class so far

```
#include "q.h"

    q::q()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < q::QUEUE_SIZE; i++) 
        {
            q::data[i] = '0';
        }
        q::front = q::rear = -1;
        printf(" YEA QUEUE HAS BEEN CREATED ");
    }

    q* q::createQueue()
    {
        return new q;
    }
```

Now in my output class (main.cpp), I want to be able to create new queues through the createQueue() function call and returning a handle to the current queue class object

Something like this

```
q* firstQueue = createQueue();
q* secondQueue = createQueue();
```

I was thinking my main constructor q() needs to be private and createQueue should act like a factory so my q.h file should be something like below?

```
#ifndef Q_H
#define Q_H
#include <stdio.h>

class q
{
public:

    void destroy_queue(q* currentQueue);
    void enque_byte(q* currentQueue,unsigned char b);
    unsigned char deque_byte(q* currentQueue);
    static q* createQueue();
private:    
    static const int QUEUE_SIZE = 2048;
    unsigned char data[QUEUE_SIZE];
    int front, rear;
    q();
};

#endif // Q_H
```

And then how would I be able to do enqueue, dequeue operations by calling

And then do enqueue and dequeue operations on any number of queues like

```
enqueue(firstQueue,5);
dequeue(firstQueue);
enqueue(secondQueue,10);
..
..
```

And not use objects to call them like

```
firstQueue->enqueue(...)
```

I am slightly confused with the organization of my code. Hope someone could provide an insight on how can I achieve such a structure?

Comment: Why do you need the factory function? What is wrong with just instantiating queues? `q firstqueue, secondqueue;`

Comment: Okay I forgot to mention but its part of c++ programming challenge that I am trying to solve which wants us to have a createQueue() function that returns a handle to that queue object!

Comment: Do you have a link to that challenge? It sounds like either there are some additional requirements that necessitate a `createQueue` function, or you misunderstood the requirements, or the challenge was written by people with a faulty understanding of what C++ should look like.

Comment: The problem statement is this -> The problem is to write a set of functions to manage a variable number of byte queues, each with variable length, in a small, fixed amount of memory.

And all the other API requirements are the same I mentioned in my initial post

Q * q = createQueue() should create a queue.
enqueue(q,data) and so on...

And the programming test is from a well known software company so I guess I am not getting the requirements :(

Comment: Sounds like you need a chatroom, not a Q&A repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write simple wrappers like

```
void enqueue(q* obj, int x) {
    obj->enqueue(x);
}
```

All this doesn't make much sense, however; the C++ idiom is to use objects and methods and, unless you are in a case where this idiom doesn't work that well (e.g. multimethods), following it is much easier than fighting against it.